# Wrangling/Tidying data (Phone numbers) using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a large number of phone numbers in different formats and I'm trying to get them all into the form '1 123 123 1234'. Effectively removing all brackets, dots and dashes. I've written below some examples.

```
123 123-123-123
(123) 123-1234
(123) 123 1234
1.123.123.1234
1(123)123-1234
(123)123-1234
1 123 123 1234
1-123-123-1234
```

The code below gets my data into the format I would like but I was wondering if there is a 'neater' or more efficient way of doing things like using a dictionary

```
temporary['number'] = temporary['number'].str.replace('.', ' ')
temporary['number'] = temporary['number'].str.replace(')', '')
temporary['number'] = temporary['number'].str.replace('(', '')
temporary['number'] = temporary['number'].str.replace('-', ' ')
```

Dictionary used would be

```
d1 = {  '.': ' ',
        ')': '',
        '(': '',
        '-': ' '
    }
```

I've tried passing this dictionary through pandas in multiple ways but I can't seem to get it to work, it always returns an unedited list. I'm sure this is a simple fix and I'm missing something very basic.

```
temporary['number'] = temporary['number'].replace(d1)
```

This will return an error, however, I believe it shows the idea I'm trying to achieve. This would replace the phone number in 'numbers' with phone numbers in this form '1 123 123 1234'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract all numeric characters from a pandas series (all groups)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876281/extract-all-numeric-characters-from-a-pandas-series-all-groups)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regular expression to remove all characters except digits and spaces

```
temporary['number'] = temporary['number'].str.replace('[^\d ]','')
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this not delete spaces? it will return a number in the form '11231231234' instead of the intended '1 123 123 1234'

Comment: Updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dic = {'number': {'\)': '', '\(': '', '-': ' ', '\.': ' '}
           }

    temporary = temporary.replace(dic, value=None, regex=True)
```

Returns exactly what I requested in the OP. I use a nested dictionary to pass a dictionary into the .replace() function.

In order to use a nested dictionary, you must set value=None and I also needed to use regex=True.

Using regex will give you numerous errors due to your search for ')' '(' and '.'. you must place a '\' in front of them as a character escape.

James' method is superior to mine however his method doesn't format the number in the way I wanted. If formatting isn't a problem use his method.